# how to use gradient descent to solve ridge regression with a positivity constraint?

Tags: regression, optimization, gradient-descent, ridge-regression, constrained-regression

I am working on ridge regression at this moment:

$$\sum{(y_{i}-\beta\cdot X_{i})}^{2} + \lambda \cdot\beta^{2}$$

with an additional constraint:

> for some $\beta_{m} > 0 $ and some $\beta_{n}<0$, while $n+m$ is the total number of predictors.

Basically, there is a positivity constraint here.

The positivity constraint makes the target function non-differentiable. I am not sure if this can still be solved by a gradient descent approach.

Can anyone share any insight here?

Comment: A constraint doesn't change the differentiability of the objective function: it merely changes its domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two recommendations depending on which case you're in. To give some immediate context, [Ridge Regression (aka Tikhonov regularization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) solves the following quadratic optimization problem:

$$
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $\mathbf{b}$)} & \sum_i \left(y_i - \mathbf{x}_i \cdot \mathbf{b} \right)^2 + \lambda \|\mathbf{b}\|^2_2  \\
 \end{array}
$$

This is ordinary least squares plus a penalty proportional to the square of the $L_2$ norm of $\mathbf{b}$.
You want to add the linear constraints that $b_j \geq 0$ for $j \in J$ and $b_k \leq 0$ for $k \in K$.

#### Case 1: self-study, if you're trying to learn how things work

One possible approach is to add a [barrier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function) to your objective function for each constraint. Then run gradient descent etc... on your new objective function. This is known as an [interior point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method).

For example, instead of the objective:

$$
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $b$)} & f(b)  \\
 \mbox{subject to} & b \geq 0
 \end{array}
$$

You could have:

$$
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $b$)} & f(b) - \frac{1}{t}\log(b)
 \end{array}
$$

Where $t$ (for $t > 0$) is some parameter that controls how sharp your barrier/penalty is. As $t$ becomes larger, the two problems become equivalent.

See the section on barrier functions and interior point methods in Boyd's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) book.

For example, here's a graph of $y = - \frac{1}{20} \log x$. As $x$ approaches $0$, the penalty $- \frac{1}{20} \log x$ approaches $\infty$.

[image]

#### Case 2: If you just want a numerical solution

This is a [quadratic optimization problem with linear constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming). There are numerous extremely well tested, optimized libraries/engines to solve this type of problem. In Matlab, one would invoke the `quadprog` function.

Comment: +1 (because I fully agree with everything and this is the correct answer - this sees like a typical QP application) but you could say in the beginning that you have to formulate this as an optimisation problem so things are immediately contextualised.

Comment: Case 1: if we use the barrier function, do you think we can solve the target function using gradient descent algorithm?

Comment: @user152503 I don't have a tremendous amount of practical experience implementing this, but it should work fine as long as your step size keeps you within the feasible set. You can check your solution against the solution calculated by some solver. Another package that can solve these types of problems is [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).